# Comment form not showing up in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written `comments_template();` in my home page but it is not showing any form there.

Its only outputting...

```
<div id="comments" class="comments-area">
</div><!-- .comments-area -->
```

...while viewing source code. I am using latest version of wordpress. What's the solution to it?

Comment: You need to add <?php comment_form(); ?>

Comment: its showing no thing

Comment: Ensure there's a `comments.php` in your template and comments are enabled on that page.

Comment: I changed my upvote to downvote as what you are asking here has apparently nothing to do with what you want... you may want to edit your question, so we can properly answer, or bear the consequences of being downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

From [WordPress's `comments_template()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/):

> Will not display the comments template if not on single post or page, or if the post does not have comments.

So make sure you have this on a single post or page, and the post has comments.

Also, very obviously, as @Alxs also states, make sure a `comments.php` file exists in your selected theme, and has relevant content (you can take [`comments.php` in WordPress's default twentysixteen theme](https://github.com/WordPress/twentysixteen/blob/master/comments.php) as an example).

**EDIT**: following your question in the comments, if you want to ensure comments are being shown by default (without the need to explicitly click on them), the following should work:

```
global $withcomments;
$withcomments = 1;
comments_template();
```

**EDIT #2**: It appears the OP meant the comments block to appear in the admin section, not on the actual home page for users to see. The above answer addresses the original question of how to force the comments block to appear on front-end pages.

Comment: under single post, i have to tick allow comments option to show comment form. Is there any way to show up comment form on every single post by default.Its not showing now by default.

Comment: sorry for my late reply but its not working.i have found the solution other way to tick the comment option under screen options.

Comment: @NirojAdhikary sorry, but this has nothing to do with what you asked. If you want to have the comments block appear under the post / page in the **admin** section, that is an entirely different thing and you should have made it clear in your original post... So either try out my solution properly on the hope page (and NOT in admin), or update the question with an edit on what you want exactly and allow me (and others) the opportunity to properly answer a proper question, because the one you asked is not one, if it's this far from what you actually wanted...